# I'm using Wine to run Windows Steam and I'm getting errors

Tags: wine, steam

Whenever I start Steam or go to my profile I get this error:

[image: error image]

Comment: how did you install steam. did you download it from the website. if you did your doing it wrong. if you want instructions on how to install Steam on Wine install playonlinux and replay to this message.

Comment: There is not enough info in your post. 1. what wine version are you running ?  2. you have posted no logs  ??? 3. clicking Show Details will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest [Wine Staging.](https://wine-staging.com/index.html) Wine Staging is a special wine version containing bug fixes and features that are not yet available in regular wine versions.

To install, run the following commands from a terminal, one line after each other.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-staging
```

If you want to avoid typing the full path each time you can additionally install the `wine-staging-compat` package which provides compatibility symlinks:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine-staging-compat
```